# Error in Angular MSAL AuthError: Unexpected error in authentication.: Hash does not contain state

Tags: angular, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I m successfully creating users in B2C using graph api. Once a user is created I want to send email to users to reset password (using the password reset link below)and then login to the angular web app using MSAL 1.3.2. I have created b2c password reset policy in Azure B2C instance. I click on `Run the user flow` to test it. The Url (which I want to email) looks like

> https://tenant.b2clogin.com/tenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_passwordreset1&
> client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4203&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login

I successfully reset password and then redirected to the app with an Id token like below in the browser address bar

> http://localhost:4203/#id_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

My angular app which I have configured using MSAL could not process this and I get an error  in the console

> ERROR AuthError: Unexpected error in authentication.: Hash does not contain state.

My b2C config looks exactly like this in [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-angular-spa/blob/master/src/app/app-config.ts)

Any suggestions?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @Carl its Google chrome

Answer (score 3):

This issue occurs when you send the user directly to B2C **without initialising MSAL in the app first**. MSAL always passes a `state` parameter in its request to the auth endpoint and expects it returned back with the tokens, where it then confirms the `state` is the same as sent in the initial request.

So this will always occur when using the **run now** link from the portal with the reply url set to your app. Use https://jwt.ms as a reply url instead or initiate the flow through your app so MSAL is properly initialised.

Comment: I totally understand what you are saying that there is no state parameter passed when we initiate the flow from b2c UI. And it does work with jwt.ms. What I m tyring to acheive is that send email to user to reset the password. How can that be done if we have a limitation of state parameter being only passed through the app login?

Comment: Your email should contain a link to the App, eg https://myapp.com/forgotpassword. The app should trigger MSAL with forgot password policyId, which send the user to B2C. Now the App has initialized MSAL properly.

Comment: Thanks alot @Jas. Can you possibly share a link to a sample (or any documentation) where we genererate this Url via MSAL to send in an email to reset password?

Comment: The URL is whatever you'd like your app to handle. It should be some 'route' in your app. Nothing MSAL specific here. For MSAL to launch the password reset flow - youd create update the msalConfig object with the requried Authority (that contains the password reset policyId), and then use the MSAL object to call acquiretokenpopup()

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, some browsers will get this error because of the limitation of the URL length. Try to set `storeAuthStateInCookie` to "true" to save the cache in a cookie to resolve the trusted zone restriction in the browser.

```
export const msalConfig: Configuration = {
    auth: {
        clientId: "e760cab2-b9a1-4c0d-86fb-ff7084abd902",
        authority: b2cPolicies.authorities.signUpSignIn.authority,
        redirectUri: "http://localhost:6420/",
        postLogoutRedirectUri: "http://localhost:6420/",
        navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true,
        validateAuthority: false,
      },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: "localStorage",
        storeAuthStateInCookie: true, 
    },
}
```

Or try using another browser.

Comment: I m using chrome and I already have `storeAuthStateInCookie` set to `true` in msalConfig. Any other ideas?

Comment: The Id token that comes back in the browser address bar is a valid token, I can see the correct user claims,  its just MSAL library could not process it and log in the user. I have not made any changes in the offical microsoft sample except adding my B2C subscription details.

Comment: @rumi  This should be a B2C service issue, you can ask the B2C team for help:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/support-options

Comment: what makes you think its a B2C service issue? The B2C service seems to reset the password and send an ID token correctly. Its my angular app using MSAL library not able to handle. I dont mind creating a ticket with the B2C team but not sure if its really that where the problem is.